# Android: styles for API-16 leaking to every higher API version

Tags: android, android-styles

I have those two folders: `values` and `values-v16`. Contents of `styles.xml` file in the `values` folder is as follows:

```
<style name="Widget.App.SearcherButtonWithIcon" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
</style>
```

And `values-v16` folder contains the same style, but with different `paddingLeft` value:

```
<style name="Widget.App.SearcherButtonWithIcon" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">26dp</item>
</style>
```

The problem is that the later one (with 26dp padding) gets applied to every view in every API version. Why is that, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. values-v16 means for devices that support api 16 **or** above. You can read more about this in the documentation: [Providing alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

If you want that only for api 16, override it again in api 17 with the default value.

Here's my recommended approach:

```
/res/values/styles.xml

<dimen name="searcher_padding_left_default">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="searcher_padding_left_v16">26dp</dimen>
<dimen name="searcher_padding_left">@dimen/searcher_padding_left_default</dimen>

/res/values-v16/styles.xml
<dimen name="searcher_padding_left">@dimen/searcher_padding_left_v16</dimen>

/res/values-v17/styles.xml
<dimen name="searcher_padding_left">@dimen/searcher_padding_left_default</dimen>
```

This way you only specify the values in one place which will probably help maintaining all values in sync in the future.